# jQuery Mobile Showing button/input value as text

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-mobile

I have got an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cByhZ/

As you can see the buttons value is appearing as text outside the button itself.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced!

Edit:

The only solution I could find was to add their themes, not much of a solution! You can view the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cByhZ/28/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the jquery version seems to be uncompatibal use version `1.3.2`

http://jsfiddle.net/cByhZ/26/

Comment: You need jQuery to run jQuery Mobile, clicking the button doesn't trigger an event in this example.

Comment: @jonathandey  i didn't know that :| but it seems the newer versions of jquery are not compatible with the jquey mobile version, i have updated the answer

Comment: I think we need to use both jQuery core and mobile?

Comment: @3nigma jQuery recommends using 1.6.4 on their own site! http://jquerymobile.com/download/ and this still causes the same problem =\

Comment: Using jQuery 1.3.2 causes problems with jQuery mobile =\

Comment: Seems to work if I use their themes...http://jsfiddle.net/cByhZ/28/
I think this is something jQuery really needs to look in to!

Thanks for the help guys...

Answer (score 0):

you were loading jquery twice look at this http://jsfiddle.net/cByhZ/5/

Comment: You've not included jQuery Mobile in this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Mobile Button</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQM Uses jQuery 1.6.4 in your example you do not add the jQM CSS. I have added the CSS Link and changed the jQuery version to 1.6.4 (See example), Changed some JS Code as well

- http://jsfiddle.net/cByhZ/31/